# How to overwrite _repaintMinorText of TimeAxis-Object of vis.js Timeline with custom function

Tags: javascript, vis.js

In a client project I need to customize the *_repaintMinorText* function of the *TimeAxis*-Object. The function is shortening date-labels which I want to prevent.

As I don't want to change the original vis.js implementation I am looking for a way to override this specific function.

My first approach was:

```
vis.timeline.timeAxis.prototype._repaintMinorText = 
   function(x, text, orientation, className) { //my custom code };
```

However this does not work.

Does someone know how to accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to the timeAxis-property is incorrect.

The right call for this task is:

```
vis.timeline.components.TimeAxis.prototype._repaintMinorText = 
  function(x, text, orientation, className) { //my custom code };
```

Answer (score 0):

Like in your example - you tried to EXTEND the function, so the original implementation did the work AND it also did actions from your original implementation extension (your custom code).

If you want to prevent from all function actions just override it like this:

```
vis.timeline.timeAxis._repaintMinorText = function() {};
```

In this example whole function body will be replaced locally with empty function.

Comment: Sorry my question was too broad. Actually my error was an incorrect path to the timeAxis-Property. Will give an answer myself to help others facing this problem thx